# The images in my listview changes when I scroll

Tags: android, listview

This is my code:

```
public class GetAllCategoriesListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

private JSONArray dataArray;
private Activity activity;

private static final String baseUrlForCategoryImage = "link here";

private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

public GetAllCategoriesListViewAdapter(JSONArray jsonArray, Activity a){
    this.dataArray = jsonArray;
    this.activity = a;

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return this.dataArray.length();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final ListCell cell;
    if(convertView == null){
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.get_all_categories_list_view_cell, null);
        cell = new ListCell();

        cell.category_name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.category_name);
        cell.category_image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.category_image);
        cell.category_image.setTag(cell);
        convertView.setTag(cell);
    }else{
        cell = (ListCell) convertView.getTag();
    }

    try{
        JSONObject jsonObject = this.dataArray.getJSONObject(position);
        cell.category_name.setText(jsonObject.getString("category_name"));

        String nameOfImage = jsonObject.getString("category_image");

        String urlForImageInServer = baseUrlForCategoryImage + nameOfImage;

        new AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap>(){

            protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params){
                String url = params[0];
                Bitmap icon = null;

                try{
                    InputStream in = new java.net.URL(url).openStream();
                    icon = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);

                }catch (MalformedURLException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }catch (IOException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                return icon;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
                cell.category_image.setImageBitmap(result);
            }

        }.execute(urlForImageInServer);
    }catch (JSONException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return convertView;
}

private class ListCell{
    private ImageView category_image;
    private TextView category_name;
}
}
```

The code gets the images from my webhost and place it in every cell in my listvew. The problem is everytime I scroll, the images are shuffled and returns in few seconds. How to stop the images from changing when I scroll? I tried to use the solution on other post but it won't work. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are new to android. So you are fetching the images in the getView method. The getView method is called every time a new list item is drawn. So For every image, a new request is made to internet. SO that will be a lot of requests . You should firstly get your images and get them in some ArryayList . Then pass that Arraylist to your adapter. Here is tutorial for you

Using AsyncTask
http://www.devexchanges.info/2015/04/android-custom-listview-with-image-and.html

Using Volley
https://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-volley/

Go for Volley for better performance. Cheers!

Comment: ok i used the AsyncTask method but my problem now is that in GetJsonFromUrlTask.java, its has this code "((ListViewActivity) activity).parseJsonResponse(result);" but mine is in Fragment how should I solve this problem?

Comment: sir can i ask how to put onclicklistener on every item and get the value of the item?

Comment: Simply put the onclick listener in the getView method . Since you get the position in the getView, simply do array.get(position) to get the item

Comment: If the answer solves your problem, please mark the answer as correct, it helps other that also face the same problem